# Did Helen treat yelling for the truth as a fight to obtain the envelope, as suggested by Benoit?

Tags: plot-explanation, glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery

Detective Benoit advises Helen to find a way to get the envelope that nobody will
question or follow, even if it means picking a fight and losing. Later,
Helen confronts the Disruptors and yells for the truth. Duke approaches her:

> Duke: I'm tired of pretending. You're the loser. That's the truth.

Then Helen walks out of the room and enters each Disruptor's room to search for the envelope.

Did Helen treat yelling for the truth as a fight to obtain the envelope, as suggested by Benoit?

Comment: I thought that her yelling was just to create a situation where leaving the room wasn't suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote the answer yourself almost, Helen needed excuse to leave the room without looking suspicious to the "Distruptors", so she will be free to look for the envelope in their rooms, Shouting at them without getting an answer and also getting insulted gave her that accuse.

Comment: You mean *excuse*, not accuse.